# How to start interaction between Solr and MVC app

Tags: model-view-controller, solr

I have installed solr on my server, I have a application in MVC .
How would I start interacting with solr from my application. I need this for fast search can anybody help me in this??

Comment: What language are you using in your MVC app?

Comment: I wanted to know , I have a stored procedure if I am using it for search it takes lot of time now i wanted to use solr and solrnet so that search will be quicker . What will be my datasource  in Solr schema , do I need to call that SP in Schema file ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you are using java then you can certainly use Solrj. if you are using php you may use Solarium etc.

Comment: I wanted to know , I have a stored procedure if I am using it for search it takes lot of time now i wanted to use solr and solrnet so that search will be quicker . What will be my datasource  in Solr schema , do I need to call that SP in Schema file ?

Comment: I am using Asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds like you might need SolrNet. Here's the link to the SolrNet GitHub page, which has examples for you to look at: [SolrNet GitHub Page](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet)

Comment: I wanted to know , I have a stored procedure if I am using it for search it takes lot of time now i wanted to use solr and solrnet so that search will be quicker . What will be my datasource  in Solr schema , do I need to call that SP in Schema file ?